# .Net 4.8 AES GCM equivalent

Tags: c#, aes-gcm

I've got the following code in .NET Core that works as expected, but the port to .NET 4.8 using BouncyCastle 2.0.0 fails with an exception:

> mac check in GCM failed

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
#if NET48
    var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
    cipher.Init(false, new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tag.Length * 8, iv, aad));
    plaintextBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(encrypt.Length)];
    int len = cipher.ProcessBytes(encrypt, 0, encrypt.Length, plaintextBytes, 0);
    cipher.DoFinal(plaintextBytes, len);
#else
    using (var decryptor = new AesGcm(key))
        decryptor.Decrypt(iv, encrypt, tag, plaintextBytes, aad);
#endif
```

*NOTE:* the `AAD` byte array in the sample data I'm using has a zero length and that I'm using the sample data from https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/zoom-apps/js-sdk/reference/#getAppContext

Comment: This one works for us, compare with yours https://github.com/lukemerrett/Bouncy-Castle-AES-GCM-Encryption

Answer (score 0):

I found my own issue. Reviewing the code closer from https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/zoom-apps/js-sdk/reference/#getAppContext (the JAVA example specifically) I noticed the BouncyCastle wants the encrypt array and the tag array merged first... so that's what I did, in that order, and the issue went away.